# Bulk Removing documents using Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Consider a aggregation, which is formed like:

```
MatchOperation matchOperation = match(Criteria.where("group").is("A")
                               .andOperator(Criteria.where("score").lt(50))) ;
SortOperation sortOperation = sort(Sort.by(Direction.DESC, "department")); 

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, sortOperation) ;
```

I want to issue a bulk remove (or basically remove each document found as a result of above) using a Spring Boot application.

**Problem:**
Unable to find a suitable method to do so, and I want to achieve this using Aggregation only ie. don't want to switch to Query.

**What I've tried already:**

1. I have already tried using `mongoTemplate.findAllAndRemove()`, but it accepts a Query and I am using Aggregation.
2. I have also tried using
   `BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkMode.ORDERED, EntityName.class) ;`
   And then, `bulkOps.remove()` but this method also accepts a `List<Query>`

Comment: Just wondering ... Why is the `sort` operation important if you want to remove all documents found with `match`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove using `aggregation` so I think there are two options:

- Using your aggregate query to get all `_id`s and do a new Query to remove these `_id`s.

Something like this (not tested):

```java
List<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "my_collection", Document.class).getMappedResults();
List<ObjectId> resultList = result.stream().map(item -> item.get("_id")).collect(Collectors.toList());


mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").in(resultList)), YourClass.class);
```

- Create a new `delete` query. As you need to use delete maybe you can avoid aggregation simply using this:

```java
mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(Criteria.where("group").is("A").andOperator(Criteria.where("score").lt(50))), YourClass.class);
```

Note that the criteria is the same as you have in the `match`. This is because is the same use it in a [find/remove/update query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EDFts8Uvdhu) and into an [aggregation query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dHHgS2E3028)

By the way, I don't understand why sort if you want to delete.